# In Colab there is a new Buildozer.spec and nothing seeems to work anylonger

Tags: deployment, google-colaboratory, buildozer

recently  in Colab site the file Buildozer.spec has changed and I'm am not able to obtain apks anymore from Python-Kivy codes. In order to generate the Buildozer.spec I'm still using the same Deploy code I used before.  Should it changed in a new version?  If yes where to find it? Thanks.

I tried to examine the Buildozer output which shows many errors that I cannot comprehend. I tried to obtain apks of many old python-Kivy  codes of mine whith the same procedure used prior the changing in Buildozer.spec, procedure that always worked, but now it doesn't anymore.